# I can't find where to change the strength of the sun in version 2.70a

Tags: rendering, node-editor, light

I have viewed the tutorials of lighting and shading, but the version used in the tutorials must be older than that I use.
[image]

Comment: If @stacker's answer didn't solve it, could you post a link to the tutorial in question?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not aware of a recent change of the energy slider in the lamp properties in the Blender internal renderer. From the image you posted you are using the blender internal renderer.

[image]

Comment: The size in Cycles only changes the sharpnes of the shadows, not the sun intensity. To change that, you have to enable 'Use Nodes'. Then you will get a 'Strength' slider for the lamp which is similar to the 'Energy' slider of BI.

Comment: @maddin45 sorry removed that part, since he is using BI.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, I am not mad at you ;) But for completeness you could add the (updated) Cycles answer anyways, so that people who are searching for the answer will find the settings for Cycles as well.